# Plotting dynamic chart using AChartEngine in one fragment on the click of a button in the other fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, achartengine

I am developing an Android application which does records data from microphone and does real-time pitch detection and plots the pitch values as graph. So far I have completed doing the pitch detection in real time. Now I want to plot the values dynamically as a graph. So the screen of my application should have 2 fragments. One has Record and Stop buttons and I want to display my graph in the other fragment. I already understood how to plot a graoh in real time using AChartEngine. Also I understood basics of using fragments. So my question is, How do I connect all these together? ie, I want to run my Pitch detection activity as well as display the graph dynamically on the click of Record button and stop the entire thing when I click on Stop button. Is there any example code which shows plotting graph on another fragment on the click of a button in one fragment?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is just my idea. What you could do is, set up both fragments, create few methods that will be used to show and supply data to the fragments (if `fragment.setArgs()` is not sufficient for your needs)

Imagine you have methods in your `SecondFragment` like, which you call when you hit the Stop, you bring the second fragment from the back stack:

```
public void showRecordedData(SomeDataModel data){
     this.mFragmentData = data;
     ///show the  data on the chart view of the second fragment
}
```

Make sure `SecondFragment` is not null and visible.

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Use ScrollView Like:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/ScrollViewChartContainer" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/main" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
       <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/chart1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="@android:color/transparent" android:orientation="horizontal" /> 
       <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/chart2" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="@android:color/transparent" android:orientation="horizontal" /> 
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I have not tested such a layout, but it should work.